# Delay between each mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

This is my code for getting the mysql table content

I am getting whole data at once.

I want to put a time delay in each of the query.

```
$host= "localhost";
$user= "xxxxx";
$pass= "xxxx";
$db="xxxxx";

$connect= mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if (!$connect)die ("Cannot connect!");
mysql_select_db($db, $connect);

$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        url
");

if($result){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$url = $row['urlss'];
echo '<li>'.$url.'</li>';
}
}
```

The result output is

```
row1
row2
row3
row4
```

I want to get output In below manner

```
row1
//wait 5 sec
row2
//wait 5 sec
row3
//wait 5 sec
row4
//wait 5 sec
```

Thanks

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You can do that client-side with JavaScript.

Comment: @JayBlanchard any example sir ?

Comment: @Vinay That comment is literally full of links to examples.

Comment: Well there's so much already wrong with this code, why not just add a `sleep(5000)` in your while loop?

Comment: You need to use ob_flush(); flush(); sleep(5); output text, sleep 5 seconds

Comment: on http(s) level browser opens socket to dedicated port and does GET /someurl, waits for output from serverside and then renders content. You cannot render html output while it's not outputted totally. So browser will wait 20 seconds and then immediately will show them all.

Answer (score 3):

Use client side script jquery/javascript to achive it.

PHP code:

```
<?php 
// code for DB connection and query

echo "<ul id='list-results'>";
if($result){
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $url = $row['urlss'];
    // display none 
    echo '<li style="display:none">'.$url.'</li>';
 }
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Jquery:

```
// include jquery
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  // read all list tlements
 $( "#list-results li" ).each(function( index ) {
    // fade in each li
    $(this).delay(5000*index).fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No I want to get each row after 5 sec. In your code sir, I am getting all rows. they are just fading in after 5 sec.

Comment: @Vinay, You're outputting html data, and it will not appear as You wish, cuz web browser keeps asking data from Your server and after it renders it. You can output them inside <li style="display:none">some data</li> and then using jquery animate them. Ravinder Reddy is right with his answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a delay, then you could try PHP's `sleep` function

```
$host= "localhost";
$user= "xxxxx";
$pass= "xxxx";
$db="xxxxx";

$connect= mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if(!$connect) die ("Cannot connect!");
mysql_select_db($db, $connect);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM url");

if($result){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $url = $row['urlss'];
        echo '<li>'.$url.'</li>';
        sleep(5); //sleep for 5 seconds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not mistaking and i understood correctly you need to use ob_flush()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
foreach ($row as $text) {
    //output text, sleep 5 seconds 
    echo $text; 
    ob_flush(); 
    flush(); 
    sleep(5); 

}
```

But javascript could be a better option in this case as you send all data to the client first and use javascript interval to iterate a $row each 5 seconds.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = ' . json_encode($rows) . '; 
    var output = document.getElementById("output-id");
    var i = 0;
    var no_rows = data.length;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
       output.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].columnName));
         i++;
         if (i >= no_rows) {
             clearInterval(interval);
         }
    }, 5000);
</script> ';
```